# Bloom and Antialiasing causing banding in Three.js render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add a glowing effect to my scene. As far as I know the best way to do is with the a bloom filter using the EffectComposer. Unfortunately using the EffectComposer negates the beautiful anti-aliasing that comes with the renderer. I added a SSAARenderPass but it causes banding even with unbiased set to true, and sampleLevel to 32. See attached pictures below.

I ran across this discussion dealing with a similiar issue: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/effect-composer-gamma-output-difference/12039/23 and I believe I integrated the discussed solution, by explicitly creating a RenderTarget for the EffectComposer that has type set to THREE.FloatType. This definitely helped, but I still have some pretty noticeable banding.

How can I have a glowing effect and preserve a clean render without aliasing or banding?

```
const pixelRatio = renderer.getPixelRatio();
const renderScene = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), 1.5, 0.4, 0.85);
bloomPass.threshold = 0.9;
bloomPass.strength = 1.5;
bloomPass.radius = 0.15;

var ssaaRenderPass = new SSAARenderPass( scene, camera );
ssaaRenderPass.sampleLevel = 32;
ssaaRenderPass.unbiased = true;

var adaptToneMappingPass = new AdaptiveToneMappingPass(true, 256);
var gammaCorrectionPass = new ShaderPass( GammaCorrectionShader );

var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth * pixelRatio, window.innerHeight * pixelRatio, 
{
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    type: THREE.FloatType
});
renderTarget.texture.name = 'EffectComposer.rt1';

composer = new EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget);
composer.addPass(renderScene);
composer.addPass(ssaaRenderPass); //Seems to be better than fxaa but has terrible banding
composer.addPass(adaptToneMappingPass);
composer.addPass(bloomPass);
composer.addPass(gammaCorrectionPass);
```

This is with no SSAA or Bloom. No banding but terrible aliasing
[image: No SSAA or Bloom]

This is with Bloom but no SSAA. No banding in the background, though there is in the bloom effect
[image: Bloom but no SSAA]

This is with both Bloom and SSAA. The aliasing is better but the banding in the background and bloom is bad
[image: SSAA and Bloom]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into the exact issue that [this demo solves](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_ssaa). When `unbiased = false` you see color banding:

[image: enter code here]

but when `unbiased = true`, the banding is fixed:

[image]

Should be a simple fix by setting `ssaaRenderPass.unbiased = true;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marquizzo. Unfortunately, I already have unbiased set to true (see code above), and while it does reduce the banding as compared to having it off, its still a problem

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I should've read your code more thoroughly! :)